# Observable.Interval with select to stateful service causes strange behaviour

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I am trying to use Observable.Interval combined with select to poll a service, it seems like a syntactically nice way to do it. However whenever I try to implement a way to wait for the observable to complete I get strange behaviour where the service invoked inside the select is invoked multiple times.

With no waiting I get the correct behaviour I am looking for...

**Code**

```
private static ConcurrentQueue<string> _data = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var observable = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        .Select(Transform)
        .TakeWhile(x => x != null);

    Console.WriteLine("Starting subcription");
    var disposable = observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Event raised for {0}", x));

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for subcription to complete");
    // need to wait here

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit. . .");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string Transform(long x)
{
    string result;
    _data.TryDequeue(out result);

    Console.WriteLine("Transform invoked [x: {0}, Result: {1}]", x, result ?? "NULL");

    return result;
}
```

**Output**

```
Starting subcription
Waiting for subcription to complete
Press any key to exit. . .
Transform invoked [x: 0, Result: a]
Event raised for a
Transform invoked [x: 1, Result: b]
Event raised for b
Transform invoked [x: 2, Result: c]
Event raised for c
Transform invoked [x: 3, Result: d]
Event raised for d
Transform invoked [x: 4, Result: NULL]
```

If I invoke the extension method wait on the observable it seems to cause Transform to be invoked twice per interval and only one of the values is returned to the event...

**Code**

```
private static ConcurrentQueue<string> _data = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var observable = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        .Select(Transform)
        .TakeWhile(x => x != null);

    Console.WriteLine("Starting subcription");
    var disposable = observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Event raised for {0}", x));

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for subcription to complete");
    observable.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit. . .");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string Transform(long x)
{
    string result;
    _data.TryDequeue(out result);

    Console.WriteLine("Transform invoked [x: {0}, Result: {1}]", x, result ?? "NULL");

    return result;
}
```

**Output**

```
Starting subcription
Waiting for subcription to complete
Transform invoked [x: 0, Result: a]
Event raised for a
Transform invoked [x: 0, Result: b]
Transform invoked [x: 1, Result: c]
Event raised for c
Transform invoked [x: 1, Result: d]
Transform invoked [x: 2, Result: NULL]
Transform invoked [x: 2, Result: NULL]
Press any key to exit. . .
```

I suspect this is because the Wait is creating a second subscription behind the scenes and the service behind my observable is stateful.

I've seen people recommend using ToTask to wait for an observable to complete, this has the same strange behaviour.

So what is the correct way to have a stateful service polled behind an observable whilst all subscribers receiving the same set of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

1. It is recommended that changes to state only happen during `Subscribe`, not other operators like `Select`. I'm not sure that's practical for your example though.
2. Your observable is a [cold observable](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#HotAndCold), meaning that each subscription re-creates everything: A new timer in the background ticking every second, a new `Select` operator, etc.. You have two subscriptions, one from `Subscribe` the other from `Wait`, so you'll have two timers, with two `Select` operators attached calling `Transform`.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Turn your observable into a hot observable
2. Eliminate a subscription (solution outlined by @Daniel Weber)

Your observable as a hot observable would look like this:

```
var observable = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .Select(Transform)
    .TakeWhile(x => x != null)
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();
```

My suggestion would be that since you're changing state in your observable, I would make it hot to ensure that you didn't end up running that twice.

Comment: The same happens for hot observables; every new subscription creates a brand new pipeline. It doesn't matter if it is cold or not.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only subscribe once to the observable. Omit the first call to `Subscribe` and just leave the call to `Wait`. If you still want to emit some log messages (as you've done in your subscription), add a `Do`-step:

```
private static ConcurrentQueue<string> _data = new   ConcurrentQueue<string>(new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var observable = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        .Select(Transform)
        .TakeWhile(x => x != null);

    Console.WriteLine("Wait for the observable to complete.");
    observable
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Event raised for {0}", x))
        .Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit. . .");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string Transform(long x)
{
    string result;
    _data.TryDequeue(out result);

    Console.WriteLine("Transform invoked [x: {0}, Result: {1}]", x, result ?? "NULL");

    return result;
}
```

Note that `Wait`will block (which is inevitable in a `Main` method). Also, it will throw when your observable is empty. If you are not interested in any values of the observable, add a `LastOrDefault`-step.

Waiting for an observable is an inherently async operation, so you should check out whether it's possible to use `ToTask` instead of `Wait` and await it in an async method.

Comment: I noticed making the observable an IConnectableObservable via the Replay() extension method solved the problem. Would replay be more desirable so you could then return this IObservable to multiple consumers and still let them all subscribe. Do only seems like a good solution when you're doing things self contained like in this example, although that is unlikely to be the way it goes forward.

Comment: Sure, `Replay` (probably together with `RefCount`) makes the observable a 'hot' observable and lets you avoid repeated computations. This is useful if you really have multiple subscribers. Note, however, that while you may observe completion in one subscription, another subscription might still be doing stuff. So be careful not to tear your app down too early.